# Boostrap modern select loaded dynmically in console but in the gui the select box is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two Twitter Bootstrap "modern style" select boxes. Unfortunately when the first select box is chosen, the second is loaded dynamically with relevant values as I can see in the console for the elements.

But in the combo box mmember none of the values are shown its empty.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="control-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Type<font color="red">*</font>
    </label>
    <div style='width: 200px;  float: left; text-align:left'>
        <select id="mtype" name="mtype" data-rel="chosen">
            <option value='M'></option>
            <option value='I'>I</option>
            <option value='C'>C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Member<font color="red">*</font>
    </label>
    <div id="cbMember" style='width: 200px;  float: left; text-align:left' data-rel="chosen">
        <select id="mmember" name="mmember" data-rel="chosen">
            <option value='M'>M</option>
            <option value='Mi'>i</option>
            <option value='Mx'>x</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have  jquery I notice in the debug console the elements are added but no in my form select box it does not appear ? Any solution to this ?

```
$("#mtype").change(function () {
        alert("TEST");     

    $('#mmember').empty();
    $('#mmember').append('<option  value="whatever">text1</option>');
    $('#mmember').append('<option  value="whatever">text2</option>');
    $('#mmember').append('<option  value="whatever">text3</option>');  
;

});
```

Comment: Could I ask why you wouldn't just hide the second drop down box and filter the options in that box based on the options in the first box? This would be a dependency and it seems like you are trying to reinvent the wheel by doing this.

Comment: An example would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GSLmE/1/

Comment: I have updated my question with jquery unfortunately its loaded in console elements but not in the gui itself what else must I do for this?